# laravel 4 got FatalErrorException after cloning the source

Tags: php, laravel-4

I got clone my source of my project but when I access the cloned, I got this error:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::getRequire(): Failed opening required '/var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/app/config/app.php' (include_path='/var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

i got searched in the net but i can't find any solutions.. do you have any idea and how to fix this issue?

```
/var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected# ls -al
total 1176
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    4096 Apr  3 16:27 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    4096 Apr  3 16:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     145 Apr  3 16:27 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root    4096 Apr  3 16:40 app
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2451 Apr  3 16:27 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Apr  3 16:42 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1087 Apr  3 16:27 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   75406 Apr  3 16:44 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     566 Apr  3 16:27 phpunit.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1795 Apr  3 16:27 readme.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1074524 Apr  3 16:27 roxbur
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     519 Apr  3 16:27 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root    4096 Apr  4 06:35 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Apr  3 16:27 workbench
```

the app/config permission

```
root@p6td-56r6:/var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/app/config# ls -l
total 92
-rw------- 1 root root 7842 Apr  3 16:30 app.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2114 Apr  3 16:27 auth.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2755 Apr  3 16:27 cache.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  443 Apr  3 16:27 compile.php
-rw------- 1 root root 3409 Apr  4 07:30 database.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  303 Apr  3 16:27 eventbrite.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  279 Apr  3 16:27 ffmpeg.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  641 Apr  3 16:27 hybridauth.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  3 16:27 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4250 Apr  3 16:27 mail.php
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr  3 16:27 packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  992 Apr  3 16:27 paypal.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1984 Apr  3 16:27 queue.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1540 Apr  3 16:27 remote.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  669 Apr  3 16:27 services.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4478 Apr  3 16:27 session.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  248 Apr  3 16:27 stripe.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr  3 16:27 testing
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  907 Apr  3 16:27 view.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  882 Apr  3 16:27 workbench.php
```

Comment: is `/var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/app/config/app.php` exists?

Comment: yes.. it is exist and I am opening it in my server

Comment: this seems to a permission issue can you paste , ls -al /var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/

Comment: this is the ls -al..

Comment: is apache/your web server running as user "root"?

Comment: ok you hvae to check permission on the config folder and the app.php file

Comment: I ls -l the config folder.. what should be the right permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Like I predicted it was a permission issue first thing is to change permission on the whole folder since you have root access to the server or do a sudo if you dont have direct access to root anymore.

$ chmod 755 -R /var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/

and secondly 

$ chmod -R o+w app/storage

That should fix the issue.
```